Canva App Development 3rd party Packages Installation Issue
I am developing a Canva app using Canva UI Starter Kit,
I had chat with Canva Chatbot that we can't install packages in order to develop UI of Apps.
In My App i need to use Multi select component .
Can anyone please confirm that wether we can install packages or not ?
Thanks
Regarding this issue I also contact Canva Support but they didnt replied and its been arround 2 months.

I had raised the topic on  Canva Community and got a response that we can install any 3rd party packages but it is strongly recommended to use UI Kit.
Thanks
